# rabbitmq hundred queue bindings to a topic exchange with hundred unique key

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Let's say I have 200 events which are going to be placed in multiple queues (or not) and I was thinking of binding each queue to a topic exchange with 200 unique keys. Am i going to see bottleneck in performance by adding 200 unique bindings between one queue and one exchange?

if yes, do I have an alternative?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is less likely (like snow on July 4th) that routing will be the most resources consuming part. For further reading on routing please refer to [Very fast and scalable topic routing – part 1](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/09/14/very-fast-and-scalable-topic-routing-part-1/) and [Very fast and scalable topic routing – part 2](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/03/28/very-fast-and-scalable-topic-routing-part-2/).

As to particular case it depends on resources available to RabbitMQ server(s), messages flow, bindings, bindings key complexity, etc. Anyway, it is always better to run some load tests first to figure out bottlenecks, but again, it is less likely that routing will be the cause of significant performance degradation.